# Textbox only give the value of the date not the date itself in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, date

Hi I am a noob in VBA and I'm having a hard time getting this one solved. I have made a userform that has 4 textboxes that is inputed by dates. The problem is everytime i retrieve the said data from my worksheet the value/code of the date is displayed, not the date. For example if I add the date 12/21/2016, and then try to call it. It will display 42544. I'm using Excel 2013. I don't have the date picker thing however I used a customized one but still got the same result.

Comment: add your code to let us help you in a most effective way

Comment: Use `.Text` instead of `.Value` like so: `Me.TextBox1.Text = ActiveSheet.Range("DateCell").Text`

Comment: yeah i did used . value i guess imma try to change it ^_^

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, try to use .Text instead of .Value. If it doesn't help, be sure that the Cell with the date is formatted as a date. Also make sure that you declare your variables as Date(Dim abc As Date) in the code.